# Pandas DataFrame.agg produces multiindex after selection with missing categories

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm still working on a reproducible example, but unfortunately, I'm an absolute beginner at pandas, and I'm lost as to what I'm doing wrong. The behavior seems like a bug in Pandas 1.2.4.

I have two dataframes, `files_df` which gives the type and complexity of source code files in several repos, and `proj_df` which gives the projects and the last time they were updated.

I am trying to pick the top two projects for each language by complexity, and it looks like this:

```py
def largest(x):
    return (
        # Pick the top two rows in each language (from the groupby) by scc_complexity
        x.nlargest(2, 'scc_complexity')
        # Combine the proj_repo values (we don't actually care about scc_complexity at this point)
        .agg({'proj_repo': lambda y: '<br>'.join(y.values)})
    )

max_proj = (
    # Pick the language and complexity columns
    files_df[['scc_lang', 'scc_complexity', 'proj_repo']]
    # Sum scc_complexity by language and repo
    .groupby(['scc_lang', 'proj_repo'], observed=True).sum()
    .reset_index()
)

max_proj = (
    max_proj
    # Select only repos updated in the last two years
    .loc[max_proj['proj_repo'].isin(proj_df.loc[proj_df['last_author_time'] > '2019-05-01', 'proj_repo'])]
    # Now pick the top repos by language complexity
    .groupby('scc_lang').apply(largest)
)
```

This should produce a frame with `scc_lang` as its index and `proj_repo` as its only column, but instead it produces this shape:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 151 entries, ('ASP', 'proj_repo') to ('XML Schema (min)', 'proj_repo')
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------     --------------  ----- 
 0   0          151 non-null    object
 1   proj_repo  0 non-null      object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 8.7+ KB
MultiIndex([(                        'ASP', 'proj_repo'),
            (                   'Autoconf', 'proj_repo'),
            (                       'BASH', 'proj_repo'),
            (                      'Batch', 'proj_repo'),
...
```

That is, there's now a multi-index, and the `proj_info` column is now a column named `0`, and the `proj_info` column is now empty.

Now for the really strange part. This code produces the correct shape if you remove the `.loc[]` selection from `max_proj`. For the life of me, I can't figure out why making a selection changes the shape of the results. I haven't been able to reproduce the results with a small complete example.

I will keep experimenting, and if I learn anything interesting, I'll report here.

*Slight update*: I've discovered that removing `observed=True` also seems to produce the correct shape—so maybe this is related to missing keys?

**Bigger update**: I managed to reproduce it, and yes, it does somehow relate to missing keys, though I'm not sure how:

```py
tdf = pd.DataFrame([['lang1', 1, 'ab'],
                    ['lang2', 2, 'cd'],
                    ['lang2', 4, 'cd'],
                    ['lang2', 3, 'ef'],
                    ['lang2', 4, 'gh'],
                    ['lang3', 2, 'ef']
                   ],
                    columns=['lang', 'size', 'name']).astype({'lang': 'category'}, copy=False).set_index('lang')

d = tdf.groupby(['lang', 'name'], observed=True).sum().reset_index()
d = d.loc[d['name'].isin(pd.Series(['ab','cd','gh']))].groupby('lang').apply(lambda x: x.agg({'name': lambda y: ' '.join(y.values)}))
display(d)
d.info()
```

|  |  | **0** | **name** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **lang** |  |  |  |
| **lang1** | **name** | ab | NaN |
| **lang2** | **name** | cd gh | NaN |

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 2 entries, ('lang1', 'name') to ('lang2', 'name')
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   0       2 non-null      object
 1   name    0 non-null      object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 356.0+ bytes
```

Removing either the 'ab' or 'ef' names triggers this, meaning it has to do with a missing category. Indeed, changing the column type back to `object` *also* fixes this issue. So it seems I've misunderstood categories...

**Another update**: I've managed to reduce it down to these two lines:

```py
tdf2 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'boof']], columns=['lang', 'name']).astype({'lang': pd.CategoricalDtype(['a', 'b'])})
display(tdf2.groupby('lang').apply(lambda x: x.agg({'name': lambda y: y.values})))
```

We're pretty minimal now. Removing almost any bit of the above code causes the resulting data frame to snap to the correct shape.

What we have here is an agg being applied to an empty dataframe produced by `.groupby('lang')`, which resurrects a category that has been removed from the data. There seems to be strangeness around the result being rejoined inside `apply()`.

One new finding here is that returning `y.values` from the `apply()` lambda is part of it: if I return `y` (the Series) instead, the strange structure doesn't happen.

Comment: Can we use either tips, flights, titanic datasets to duplicate your issue?

Comment: Good idea, I'll see if I can reproduce it with one of them.

Comment: Have a look at my update.

Comment: I thinkyou'r doing some extra stuff also, `d.loc[d['name'].isin(pd.Series(['ab','cd','gh']))].groupby('lang')['name'].agg(' '.join)`  Try this statement with category, does that generate needed information?

Comment: Tried it on the mini-example at the bottom, and funny enough, that produces a series where all three of the categories are labels, and the missing category has a value of None. So that's enlightening, the category type seems very rigid. Unfortunately, in the full code the `apply()` is necessary because of the `nlargest()` call.

Answer (score 2):

At last, I found it. The strange structure results because the result of a single-column agg on an empty dataframe is a DataFrame, but if the DataFrame has rows, the result is a *Series*:

```py
tdf2 = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['lang', 'name'])
print(type(tdf2.agg({'name': lambda y: y.values})))

tdf2 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'boof']], columns=['lang', 'name'])
print(type(tdf2.agg({'name': lambda y: y.values})))
```

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

The groupby's `apply()` returns the strange structure because it's trying to combine the two:

```py
tdf2 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'boof'], ['b', 'toop']], columns=['lang', 'name'])
print(tdf2.groupby('lang').apply(lambda x: x['name'] if x.iloc[0,0] == 'a' else x))
```

```
           0 lang  name
lang                   
a    0  boof  NaN   NaN
b    1   NaN    b  toop
```

I don't know if I would call that a bug. It's certainly surprising behavior, and programs in general [should not be surprising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

**Update**: Filed as https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/41672.

**Update 2**: Now that I understand how categories work, the ultimate fix to the original code is to add `observed=True` to the groupby before the apply, eliminating the empty dataframes.